# canSendText returns false

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to send sms through my current app.

```
 if ([NSClassFromString(@"MFMessageComposeViewController") canSendText])
```

I have tried the above line, but it returns false? I am sure I can send sms through my phone (using real device for testing), so is there any setting I am missing?

So tried this:

```
   Class smsClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMessageComposeViewController"));
   if(smsClass != nil)
   {
      if ([smsClass canSendText])
      {
          [self presentMessageComposeViewController];
      }
   }
```

smsClass returns nil.

Help much apprecaited.

Comment: It is using OS version > iOS 4.0 right?

Comment: Also make sure MessageUI.framework is imported to project.

Comment: MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate         
 
implement this delegate in .h file file and also dont forget to write this line

    smsClass.messageComposeDelegate=self; and BTW no need to take smsClass here.Just check it using [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]

Comment: Yes ACB is right, I forgot to add MessageUI.framework :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    controller.body = @"Hello Test massage";
    controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12345678", @"87654321", nil];
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Anyways I can hide the sms screen and send in the background (with users permission) and putting my own number as the sender?

Comment: Yes it is working for me after I changed the recipient to my own phone number.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) canSendText is available only for iOS 4 and above.

So if you are running your device with iOS 3 your application behaviour is normal.

And why are you using NSClassFromString , the following should work (on iOS 4 and more) :

```
[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([NSClassFromString(@"MFMessageComposeViewController") canSendText])
```

will always return false. Because `canSendText` works only for class `MFMessageComposeViewController`. But `NSClassFromString(@"MFMessageComposeViewController")` will return a class (not `MFMessageComposeViewController` class).

May be you can try like this.

```
 Class smsClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMessageComposeViewController"));
   if(smsClass != nil)
  {
      if ([(MFMessageComposeViewController *)smsClass canSendText])
      {
          [self presentMessageComposeViewController];
      }
   }
```

or you can simply use

```
[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText];
```

Comment: can not simply use [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]; Otherwise getting this error:
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RegistrationPage.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)